# Make Groovy proxy (from as-coercion) delegate toString()

Tags: groovy, coercion

I have an interface and a class that implements the interface's methods but does not use the `implements` keyword to do so. Because of this I use `as`-coercion on instances of the class. This has worked as intended so far but it doesn't for `toString()` which is called on the proxy instead of the actiual instance.

Consider the following example:

```
class CoercionToString {

    public static main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.foo();
        println a;

        B b = new A() as B;
        b.foo();
        println b;
    }
}

class A {
    void foo() {
        println "foo"
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "bar";
    }
}

interface B {
    void foo()
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
foo
bar
foo
A1_groovyProxy@197d671
```

I want to be able to override `toString()` but it is - unlike other methods - not delegated to the actual object. Is there a way to make the proxy object behave that way?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me using trait instead of intefrace:

```
class CoercionToString {

    public static main(String[] args) {
        B b = new A() as B;
        b.foo();
        println b;
        println b.toString();
    }
}

class A {

    void foo() {
        println "foo"
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "bar";
    }

}

trait B {
    public abstract void foo()
    public abstract String toString()
}
```

Comment: The use of interfaces is needed because it's a mixed Java and Groovy project. I now use the `implements` keyword explicitly in the few cases where `toString()` support is required.